# %1 is not a valid win32 application when loading mod_userdir.so

Tags: php, apache

I am trying to run php on my computer, but I have encountered series of problems when loading modules. This is the most recent one and I would be very happy if someone could help me out. I have been searching the net for a solution all day, but nothing has done the trick yet. I am using XAMPP.

So I get this error
    httpd: Syntax error on line 182 of C:/xampp/apache/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot 
    load C:\xampp\apache\modules\mod_userdir.so into server: %1 is not a 
    valid Win32 application.

This is the line I added to the httpd.conf file.
    LoadModule php7_module "c:/php-7.0.1-Win32-VC14-x64/php7apache2_4.dll"

I have installed both the php and apache for thread safe win64

Any suggestions?

Comment: It is for windows. 
I have started the apache and mysql from xampp, but when I do it from the shell it is giving me the error. 
I can open localhost, but all I receive is source code, the program is not executing

Comment: Is the line 182 of httpd.conf the one you have added?

Comment: No, I added it at the end of the list for all the modules in the file. Does it have to be at the end?

Comment: No, but what is then the line 182?

Comment: Oh, sorry. Just saw the error actually says  line 182

Comment: Do you have a solution to my problem @OrtomalaLokni ?